# Compounds in -ια and -σις

Tags: vocabulary, ancient-greek, neologism, compound-noun

I greatly enjoy finding properly constructed (i.e. non hybrid grammatically ancient) equivalents to pseudo-classic neologisms.
That is the background.
I was wondering what the proper translation would be in (Ancient) Greek. The word is supposed to mean "the type of home sickness you feel when your home is not gone but is changing" hence the sickness and yearning for the solace one finds at home. The closest thing I came up with so far is: Παρηγοριαλγια (Paregorialgia) from "παρηγορια" (solace). I am unsure though how the -ια suffix is to be treated in compounds. The word most Latin-Greek lexicons have is παραμυθιον, which seems to be more close to verbal consolation to me than general relief expressed by solace. Lastly one might compound "ανακουφισιταλγια".
Are these with regards to the components grammatically and lexically correct?

Comment: Neither παρηγορία nor ἀνακούφισις has any kind of association with homes, and neither primarily means 'solace'.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Hey Cairnarvon, I was unsure about that but what does then? The Latin-Greek lexicon gives: solatium: paramythion. But latter is evidently verbal solace only. The other ones might have the menaing secondarily but they seemed to me to be more general.

Comment: παρηγορία is built on ἀγορεύω, when it's about consolation it's about verbal consolation as well. ἀνακούφισις is generic relief (κοῦφος 'light' → κουφίζω 'to be light; to lighten' →ἀνακουφίζω 'to lift up, lighten'), so if anything it's too general, which I think is a problem you'll have no matter what you pick in this general area. I'd look to words meaning 'home' specifically, though I don't think this is really a separable idea from νοσταλγία generally (νόστος 'return home').

Comment: @Cairnarvon Thank you for clearing up. However I do not understand why I should look for a word meaning home. Because said feeling is about the relief one feels at home that is then lost and pained for. So it is not really about the home itself anymore then. It appears to me that solacium is no less general than anakouphisis, although I get your point hat the base meaning is sensual and could mean multiple things. Another proposition could be "παραψυχαλγια" from "παραψυχη"same. "Cooling the pain". Same generality problem? Question is also whether my compoundings are morohologiclly correct.